Can I say "the overhead or the running costs of electricity"?
When I was looking up overhead and running costs, I found that they seemed to refer to the total costs of electricity, rent, wages, etc. Therefore, I wonder if I can break these costs down into different categories and say:

Offering online classes allows universities to cut their [overhead/running costs] of electricity and many operational activities.

I've also tried to find some examples of them used in this way but couldn't, which made me further question the validity of this usage.

Overheads and running costs are not the same thing. The definitions are a bit vague, but  overheads are typically the fixed costs (e.g. a standing charge payable for a utility). Running costs could mean non-fixed costs (per unit electricity), or refer to most costs incurred running a service (except capital expenditure). If you're contrasting the two, then running costs would probably mean the per-unit fee for electricity, payable in addition to the regular fee for the connection. I guess you want "running costs".

In the US we'd say "cost of operations" not "costs ... of operational activities".

The answer to your main question is yes, you can break down your description of costs in any way that is helpful to you and your readers.
The terms you are using will have a more or less precise meaning depending on context. One way of defining them is that the overhead(s) are a specific set of fixed costs that are treated separately to proportional operating costs (often called direct costs).
For example, imagine a company that manufactures and sells clothing. The cost of material to make the clothing will be a direct cost, because if you make more clothing you will need to buy more material. But the cost of renting the building is an overhead, because the monthly rent will be the same no matter how the company sales go up or down.
But this way of understanding overheads is a technical accounting term. With your definitions from Collins, costs such as rent and salaries are given as examples for both overheads and running costs. That's not how an accountant would think. But these are general purpose definitions, and the important word in each case is regular. So in your example, any normal and continuing cost of the university could be understood as either overheads or running costs.
Unless you have a reason to distinguish between these types of cost, I would suggest that you keep it simple: describe them as costs, and give illustrations to the extent that you think is helpful:

Offering online classes allows universities to cut costs such as electricity, rent and administrative wages.

(Note that in this setting the word cost is implied throughout. Although electricity in isolation means a form of energy, the context tells us that we are talking not about the electricity itself, but the cost of using it.)

You could say "running costs, such as electricity..."  The usual reason to use a general term like "running costs" or "overheads" is so you don't need to mention the specifics.  So it might be more natural to say "reduce the money spent on electricity ..."
Note that "overheads" would be used in the plural in your example.

Just "such as electricity"? Is "electricity" an expense? I thought it only refered to the type of energy, which is why I always feel the urge to say "electricity bills" or "electricity costs" as in "running costs such as electricity costs, maintenance costs, etc."

Regarding "overhead", there seems to be a transatlantic spelling difference.

Electricity can be an expence by metonymy  We can talk about "gas" and "water" and "electricity" as expenses with the understanding that we are talking about "the cost of electricity" etc.  "Overhead" can be used attributively "overhead costs" or as "overheads", the meaning is the same (I don't think there is a spelling difference)
